# Broadcasting across an indexed array Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm looking for a Numpy (i.e. hopefully faster) way to perform the following:

```
import numpy as np                                                              

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5],dtype=np.double)                                       
arr = [[1,2],[0,4,3],[1,4,0],[0,3,4],[1,4]]                                 

ans = np.array([ x[item] - x[i] for i, item in enumerate(arr) ])
```

I'd like to get rid of the list comprehension and do this something like this (although, I know this won't work)

```
x[arr[:]] - x[:]
```

`arr` is always a nested list of integers with length equal the length of `x`.  The interior lists are not necessarily the same length (i.e. `arr` is a ragged list)

Comment: If `arr` is a ragged list, then `ans` can not always be made into an `np.array`. So `ans`, in general, will have to be a Python list of lists. Therefore, you probably can't do better than using a list comprehension.

Comment: You could pad your `arr` with `nan`'s, turn it into a 2D numpy array, and then do `x[arr] - x[:, None]` to get your `ans`, then discard the `nan`'s, although I doubt it will speed things at all, since you are probably still going to need a python `for` loop over the items of `arr`.

Comment: You can get a ragged `np.array` but it has to be of `object` dtype.

Comment: @tiago: actually you can't.  You can write `array([[1, 2], [3]], dtype=object)`, true, but it's not actually ragged: it has shape `(2,)`.  When you multiply it by 2, for example, you get `array([[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3]], dtype=object)`, not `array([[2,4], [6]])`, because it's a regular array of lists, not a ragged array of ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution that is adequate enough for my application using Numpy masked arrays.  In my application, the `arr` list is not "too ragged" (i.e. the max length of any interior list is not extremely different from the min length of any interior list).  Therefore, I start by padding `arr` with `-1`s, then create a mask based on the location of the `-1`s.  I perform my operation and use the mask on the resulting array.  In this case, there are a few extra calculations being done unnecessarily (on the padded entries), but this is still faster that the Python loop (by a factor of almost 2).  The example code is below:

```
import numpy as np                                                              
import numpy.ma as ma

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5],dtype=np.double)                                       
arr = [[1,2],[0,4,3],[1,4,0],[0,3,4],[1,4]]                                     

max_arr_length = max([ len(item) for item in arr ])                          

arr_padded = [ np.pad(i,(0,max_arr_length-len(i)), mode='constant', 
    constant_values=-1) for i in arr ]
arr_masked = ma.masked_equal(arr_padded,-1)

ans_masked = ma.masked_array(x[arr_masked] - x[:, None], mask=arr_masked.mask)
```

This is a bit of a hack, but it works well enough for me.  It would be nice if Numpy had support for ragged arrays.